# Tools for bluetooth monitoring

Tags: bluetooth, monitoring

For my project I have an Android phone and an Arduino device that communicate via Bluetooth. I was wondering if anyone knows any software tools I could use to monitor a bluetooth communications between two devices. Something like a packet eavesdropping. Preferably for Linux.

Comment: You mean RF sniffing of packets over the air?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ubertooth one](http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/hardware/one/). In the linked webpage there are instructions on how to build the dongle, as well as links to shops selling assembled dongles may be bought. Ubertooth one should work well with Kismet, and thus in Linux, by using a BT plugin (disclaimer: I have no personal experience on this).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are after a Bluetooth sniffer.

Bad news: They are almost exclusively Windows OS based and cost mega-$.

http://www.fte.com/products/bluetooth.aspx

If you were using BlueZ for one side of the communication you could use the BlueZ HCIDUMP app and Wireshark.

I don't think anyone has made a Linuz/Bluez Sniffer - could be wrong.